# Wordpress контент страницы, размеченной в php

Tags: php, wordpress

Мне необходимо получить html контент страницы перед передачей клиенту.
(Чтобы сгенерировать содержание).

У меня есть страницы, размеченные непосредственно в php в файлах page-{id страницы}.php.

Для страниц, которые размечены внутри редактора есть возможность сделать это так:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'filter_the_content_in_the_main_loop', 1 );
 
function filter_the_content_in_the_main_loop( $content ) {
//anycode
}
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_content/

Но для уникальных страниц , с отдельными шаблонами , у которых контент внутри файла page-{id страницы}.php такой метод ничего не возвращает. Поскольку их контент отсутствует.

Как я могу сделать это? Возможно есть не wordpress методы, а чистые php?

Comment: а что сделать то нужно?

Comment: https://wp-kama.ru/id_1513/kama_contents.html#tocmenu я хочу использовать это решение для генерации содержимого. Но оно работает на пред обратке контента по хуку. По этому мне нужен html контент страницы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте такой код в ваш плагин:

```
function my_html_start() {
    ob_start();
}

add_action( 'init', 'my_html_start' );

function my_html_end() {
    $html = ob_get_clean();

    if ( $html ) {
        // Add table of contents to html.
        // ...

        echo $html;
    }
}

add_action( 'shutdown', 'my_html_end', - PHP_INT_MAX );
```

До начала вывода на экран здесь открывается буфер вывода. В самом начале действий по shutdown мы получаем буфер вывода в переменную $html с полным кодом страницы, внутрь которой можно добавить оглавление. Потом полный код страницы с оглавлением выводим на экран.

Comment: Спасибо большое,очень помог.Я уже думал придется переезжать в редактор wordpress:)